# Matlab gplot extra customly defined colors

Tags: matlab, graph, colors, plot

I have a question regarding Matlab's function [`gplot`](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/gplot.html). I would like to call `gplot` several times in a `for`-loop to plot several graphs/paths in the same figure.
However, I would like to use more colors than standardly available. With the ordinary plot command this can, for example, be done in the following way:

```
plot([1 2],[3 4],'Color',[rand rand rand])
```

but this seems not possible within `gplot`. Does anyone know how to do this. My code is currently:

```
col=char('r', 'g', 'm', 'y','r', 'g', 'm', 'y')
hold all
for i=1:k
gplot(Cell_Matrix{i},coordinates,col(i))
end
hold off
```

So now I have repeated using the same color (excluding some I do not want), but I would like to add way more new colors (around 25 extra).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the cleanest solution, but you could manipulate Matlab's default plotting order.  So before your existing code, call:

```
figure;
colors = get(gca,'ColorOrder');
```

`colors` now contains the color data for Matlab's default color cycle when using `hold all`.  You should be able to delete and add rows of RGB values to this matrix.

For example, to just use `k` random colors:

```
colors = rand(k, 3);
```

Once this matrix is set to your satisfaction, just replace the color order in your current axes with:

```
set(gca,'ColorOrder',colors)
```

Then execute a modified version of the remainder of your posted code:

```
hold all;
for i=1:k
    gplot(Cell_Matrix{i},coordinates)
end
```